# attribute mapping between salesforce and WSO2

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I want to know if it possible to map attibutes between salesforce and wso2.
I can create my custom attributes on salesforce, but i want to map attirbutes  with my WSO2 IDP configuration i.e salesforce configured as IDP within WSO2.

For eg:
If i choose to login with my salesforce account to my web app with  my user of salesforce say abc@salesforce.com login must be successful only if same user exists in WSO2 IDP. Though the credentials for abc@salesforce.com user are correct w.r.t to salesforce account ,user must login only if same username exists in wso2 idp.

I tried with claim mapping but no luck.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the claim mapping is the correct way.

You need to define whole data path
SP claim->IdP dialect claim->user attribute->local dialect claim->SP claim

If you use a federation IdP (SF), you may want to set 'provisioning' of the user, storing their identity and attributes localy (so you can see what attributes are passed and recognized.

Have fun

Comment: I have set  proper user attributes in my SF IDP.
But i am not sure WSO2 can really do the federation. I can see the attribute value set against the claim in wso2 but no federation happening.

I am not sure what exact steps i amy need to follow.
I was able to do federation using same attributes in openAM.

Comment: I also did not understand what you tried to say here, "You need to define whole data path SP claim->IdP dialect claim->user attribute->local dialect claim->SP claim" .?